# OpenQuery with parameters in function/procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a function which uses standard query and open query.

```
    CREATE function [dbo].[udf_funcForAll](@DateFrom datetime, @DateTo datetime, @param smallint)
returns table
as
return (
    select * from  [dbo].[udf_func] ('2016-10-01','2017-03-15',0) 
    union all 
    select * from  openquery(l1,'select * from [dbo].[udf_func] (''2016-10-01'',''2017-03-15'',''0'')') 
    union all 
    select * from  openquery(l1,'select * from [dbo].[udf_func] (''2016-10-01'',''2017-03-15'',''0'')') 
    union all 
    select * from  openquery(l2,'select * from [dbo].[udf_func] (''2016-10-01'',''2017-03-15'',''0'')')
```

I would like to use my parameters @DateFrom,@DateTo and @param in my queries.

When I try create procedure with following query I get error : "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
"

```
declare @DateFrom DateTime = '2016-10-01'
declare @param int = 1


declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max) = 'select * from  [dbo].[udf_func] ('''+@DateFrom+''',''2017-03-15'','+@param+')'
```

How to pass dateTime in query as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert all in nvarchar or cast it to nvarchar. sql can not + multiple data types. use this for example :

```
    declare @DateFrom NVARCHAR(100) = '2016-10-01'
    declare @param NVARCHAR(100) = 1

    DECLARE @sqlquery nvarchar(max) = 'select * from  [dbo].[udf_func] ('''+@DateFrom+''',''2017-03-15'', '+@param+')'
```